# Can I do multiple WHERE for 1 SELECT (mysql)?

Tags: php, html, mysql, wamp

I don't know if I am stupid or not but I'm not sure if I can do

`SELECT field 1 FROM table WHERE field 1=value 1 AND field 2=value 2 AND field 3=value 3`

or

`SELECT field 1, field 2, field 3 FROM table WHERE field 1=value 1 AND field 2=value 2 AND field 3=value 3`

I don't know if this stupid or not or maybe there a risk like result not found or error or something in future if I use the first one, I don't know.

I tried the first one and it worked but I afraid if something will happen in future.

I did google but can't find anything, maybe because my keyword lol.

Tldr; only field 1 is what I want, so do I need to include field 2 and field 3 too in SELECT as in WHERE?

Also I am a beginner and new here, and english is not my native language, so I'm sorry if this look rude to you and I don't meant to. Thanks!

Comment: Your query has one `where` clause with multiple boolean expressions.  There are no multiple `where` clauses.

Comment: If you just want `field1`, then you just need to select `field1`. The `WHERE` clause can include conditions for other fields that are not being selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Both of them are correct!**

if you want to filter out by more attributes then you can add ***WHERE*** as much as you need, it has nothing to do with ***SELECT*** attributes. ***SELECT*** gives you the output and ***WHERE*** filters out the data to get to the point outputs

Comment: Nice. This is all I need to know, for now. Might ask another question later.

Answer (score 2):

You can do both query and it will work fine.

SELECT clause can accept various fields as needed.

As with WHERE clause, you can also have multiple check with either `OR` and/or `AND` to merge them. It all depends on your requirement.

For example, you can do these and it will work fine:

- `SELECT field1 WHERE field1 = value1 OR (field2 = value2 AND field3 = value3)`
- `SELECT field2 WHERE field2 = value2 AND field3 = value3`

As for the `TLDR;` section:

> Tldr; only field 1 is what I want, so do I need to include field 2 and field 3 too in SELECT as in WHERE?

If field1 is all you need, you can safely ignore mentioning field2, field3, etc in WHERE clause.

Take a look at this [MySQL SELECT documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) for more info.

Comment: So that means I can do SELECT field 1 WHERE field 2=column 2?

Comment: @cloud correct. You can combine all fields into SELECT and WHERE respectively, based on your needs.

Answer (score 2):

**You can use both Both are correct.**
if you want to use one or more condition in the same query use **And** the condition